# iphone 4 inch and 3.5inch storyboard messing with me

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

all i need is (from top to bottom):

a toolbar.

my image.

my label.

what am i doing wrong? do i need to create a full layout for each screen size?

is there no way i can say like.. toolbar stick to bottom, image stick to toolbar, label stick to top..?

[image]

[image]

any help or hint will be much appreciated.

Comment: Where is your code? Where are your screenshots?

Comment: You have not provided us enough information to assist you. Are you using auto-layout? What problem are you actually having and what is the expected outcome (for whichever orientations you are supporting)? As for your questions: Yes - a toolbar can stick to the bottom of the screen; Yes - an image can stick to the toolbar; Yes - a label can stick to the top. But what problems are you having?

Comment: sorry my image uploads were failed apparently..

Comment: Very simple, no other orientations needed or anything, just need this to look decent on the 2 screen sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use iOS Autolayout feature.By using this you can set the constraints like toolbar stick to bottom, image stick to toolbar, label stick to top etc..
Reffer  http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1